# Загрузка изображения и привязка

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

У меня есть код для загрузки изображения в `Image`, привязка работает, но в рантайме выдает ошибку(не исключение, т.к. приложение не падает): `Cannot convert '<null>' from type '<null>' to type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: ImageSourceConverter cannot convert from (null).` Из-за этой ошибки загруженная картинка не показывается, хотя в коде для загрузки реализовал интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged в качестве отдельного метода в отдельном классе, который вызывается в сеттере свойства, привязанного к `Image`.
Разметка изображения:

`<Image Source="{Binding _AvatarPath}" Margin="53,56,981,558"/>`

Класс для загрузки изображения C#:

```
internal class ProfileEditor : INotifyPropertyChangedImp
{
    private readonly INotifyPropertyChangedImp propchange = new INotifyPropertyChangedImp();

    public static Uri? AvatarPath;
    public Uri? _AvatarPath
    {
        get { return AvatarPath; }
        set
        {
            AvatarPath = value;
            propchange.NotifyPropertyChanged("_AvatarPath");
        }
    }

    public static void ChangeAvatar()
    {
        OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        fDialog.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
                         "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
                         "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
        fDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
        if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(fDialog.FileName);
            AvatarPath = uri;
        }
    }
}
```

Класс, реализующий интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
internal class INotifyPropertyChangedImp : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    internal void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propname = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
        }
    }
}
```

Изначально, метод для загрузки картинки в `Image` в разметке был в файле xaml.cs, позже я решил его перенести в отдельный класс.

Собственно, у меня есть несколько вопросов:

1. Можно ли таким образом реализовывать интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged? Возможно я его просто неправильно реализовал, подскажите пожалуйста.
2. Какой лучше метод привязки здесь использовать? Возможно я и привязку неправильно сделал.
3. Как все-таки избавиться от ошибки, описанной выше(`Cannot convert '<null>' from type '<null>' to type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: ImageSourceConverter cannot convert from (null).`). Честно, первый раз сталкиваюсь с этим, и понятия не имею что здесь нужно делать.
4. Может ли быть все это из-за того, что в свойстве `AvatarPath` используется `nullable?`(прошу, поправьте если не так это называется) после типа данных?

Буду рад любой помощи, спасибо!

Comment: `private readonly INotifyPropertyChangedImp propchange` - зачем это, если у вас наследованием и так реализуется он? Просто используйте его методы.  `Какой лучше метод привязки здесь использовать` - он один, где задается `DataContext`, а затем привязывается к публичному свойству, все. `Как все-таки избавиться от ошибки` - это ошибка привязки, которая говорит, что указанное свойство == NULL, почему оно такое - может потому, что вы задаетсе путь приватному полю `AvatarPath`, когда само свойство не затрагивается и зовется у вас `_AvatarPath`? И да, вот это `Margin="53,56,981,558"` очень плохо!

Comment: Но ведь и поле и свойство публичные, я не очень понял о чем вы написали, что свойство не затрагивается. Я задал ```DataContext```, но по прежнему ничего не получается

Comment: Свойство (в отличие от поля) состоит из геттера и сеттера (`get; set;`). Это по сути 2 метода, которые так красиво вот сделали в языке.  Когда вы пишете `var someValue = Свойств;` - вы обращаетесь к свойству, забирая его значение, в этот момент происходит вызов геттера, выполняясь весь код, который там задан. Когда вы пишете `Свойство = 123;` - вы задаете свойствую значение, в этот момент вызывается сеттер и вся его логика. Сейчас вы задаете значение **полю**, а вся логика свойства (включая оповещение интерфейса об изменениях через INPC) не вызывается.

Comment: Как оказалось, дело ни в свойствах, ни в интерфейсе INPC. Дело в том, что я пытаюсь к Image(в форме) привязать тип Uri(а именно свойство типа Uri). Насколько я понимаю, проблема в том, что тип Image и тип Uri нельзя преобразовать друг к другу. При попытке вывода изображения, на самом деле, у меня пытается выводиться Uri путь вместо изображения. Возможно есть какие-то свойства в этих типах, о которых я не знаю.
Код, который я описал в проблеме на самом деле рабочий, и дело даже не в привязке, она тоже рабочая.
Теперь я пытаюсь найти решение новой проблемы, возможно у Вас есть совет?

Comment: Я наверно что-то [не так делаю](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIU6l.png)?

Comment: У меня привязка к свойству идет из другого класса. Если я помещу метод в xaml.cs, то у меня тоже все будет работать. Я хочу разобраться, как мне сделать рабочий метод в другом классе, а не в базовом для xaml файла. Я бы не стал задавать вопрос, если бы сделал так, как Вы. Я не указываю путь в коде. Я указываю путь динамически через OpenFileDialog, хотя не думаю, что это на что-то влияет в данном случае.

Comment: Вы меня запутали.... У вас изначально проблема какая? `Cannot convert '<null>'` - то есть, вы привязываете **пустое свойство**. Я вам сказал почему оно пустое - **вы ему не задаете значение**, ибо задаете полю. Потом вы говорите "Нет, дело не в привязках, дело в том, что я привязываю `Uri`, который не подходит к `Image` - я вам дал самый простейший пример, в котором показал, что это не так. Теперь вы говорите "Ну если бы я это в коде окна сделал, то все сработало бы"... Ок, только при чем тут это? Разберитесь пожалуйста, что конкретно вам надо, ибо сейчас вы ерунду пишете, не слушая советы.

Comment: Мой код действительно был рабочим, Прошу прощения за приведение в заблуждение. Я решил свою проблему через присвоение x:Name к Image в разметке, и уже в коде присвоил свойству Image.Source динамический путь.

Comment: Ну, раз считаете это нормальным - дерзайте, останавливать не буду. Знайте просто, что сейчас вы нарушаете принципы WPF, ибо вы не должны вообще хотеть обращаться к контролам через код, у вас не должно быть имен (если только они не для стилей). `Мой код действительно был рабочим` - чтож тогда у вас не работает привязка, которую вы вовсе убрали?) Я бы не назвал это "рабочим".